# Hadoop performance analysis (Wordcount vs Grep)

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, grep, word-count

I am working on Hadoop performance analysis and I am running some benchmarks on Hadoop. What's surprising is that Grep takes almost 1/10 of the time it takes wordcount to run which is very non-intuitive. Can anyone explain why is this true?

Comment: How big is the dataset you're working with? How big is your cluster?

Comment: What would you expect the performance ratio to be? Why?

Comment: The dataset is about 2 GB. I would assume performance should be equal, or grep would actually take more time. A wordcount map task takes about 40 seconds running on a 64 MB input split. Grep map task takes only 4 seconds. I am running on a 4 machine cluster but this doesnt really matter as I am comparing the Map Task timings.

Comment: @Keeto: how many grep patterns are you using? How often do they match? Have you made some attempt to match all words, for example?

Comment: I will try matching all the words and see how performance differs. However, I though checking if a pattern matches or not is what actually takes most of the time but I will look into that. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of the work in the map-reduce idiom is the communication between mappers and reducers.

In the WordCount example, *every word* results in an output record (and a reducer input). In the Grep example, every matched pattern results in an output record. If the pattern doesn't match very often, that's not very many records.

I would expect the mappers to run in roughly the same amount of time, since both will be I/O bound, up to the point where they produce output. The CPU difference between the two tasks is negligible. However, a big difference between the amount of output will be highly noticeable.